# Is 6/4 compound time?

Tags: notation

In my workbook 6/4 appears to be categorized as compound duple time but in this exercise where I am supposed to complete 4 bar rhythms the author has a grouped triplet quaver at the beginning and I dont understand that. In compound time arent beats divided into 3 anyway so why would you have the 3 on top of the quavers? I thought that you only used triplets quavers with the 3 on top when you wanted to notate triplets in simple time. Here is an example. The top rhythm I have already completed.
[image]

Comment: 6/4 is virtually the same as 6/8, the only difference is what is considered a beat is double in 6/4 time than what is the case with 6/8 ie 6/4 has dotted minim beats (Dotted half-notes) vs the dotted crotchet (Dotted quarter notes) in 6/8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, 6/4 is compound duple.   There's a top-level division of each measure into two dotted-half beats.   Three quarter notes making a beat don't need a triplet.

We're not discussing top-level here though.  We're looking inside one of those dotted-half-note beats.  There's a 3-split into three quarter-notes.   Dotted quarter and eighth add up to the first two, then triple eighths for the third.

Two main beats in each measure.  Those two beats can subdivide any way they like.

All of the below are fine in 6/4.

[image]

Comment: oh ok so it is only the top level division that divides one dotted half note into 3 quarter notes? Thereafter those quarter notes are divided as though they are in simple time where you have to use the 3 above to indicate 3 8th note triplets to the quarter note. In 6/8 you dont do this, that is why I was getting confused.

Comment: @armani: Even in 6/8 if you have 3 8th notes in the time of one quarter note you have to mark it as a triplet (with a '3'). The '3' means "squeeze three notes into the time that would normally only fit two", i.e. the notes are slightly shorter than they would otherwise be.

Comment: @psmears is correct - but has inverted a rather extreme case!

Comment: @psmears yes ok but dont we use dotted quarters in 6/8?

Comment: @armani: It depends what you're using them for! They have different meanings, and it depends on the rhythm one is trying to write. When 8th notes are part of a triplet, they're not really 8th notes (in terms of duration) - they're really "12th notes", but there isn't a separate symbol for that (fortunately, or else things would get very confusing!). In 6/8 you can have ♩. or ♩♪ or 3\[♪♪♪]♪ (triplet of 3 eighth notes then a single 8th note) - or lots of other things besides - as the first half of your bar.

Answer (score 6):

Just like 6/8 is also two lots of 3/8 - hence a sort of two in the bar, 6/4 is two lots of 3/4 - hence a sort of two in the bar. 6 beats split down the middle.

Anywhere you like, there can be a triplet. It's simply three notes in the time of two. So, in the example, that triplet comes on the count of 3, (out of the 6 counts in a bar). As in counting 6 in a bar - **1**, 2, 3-e-e-, **4**, 5, 6.

Really not anything to do with 6/4/ being compound, duple, or anything.

Are you sure this book and its exercises are helping anything? I do question the questions.

Comment: Yep, the triplet is just one of 6 quarter notes in the bar regardless of the time sig. It’s the obvious way to write that rhythm.

Comment: Triplets dont mean anything different in compound sigs. It is still just 3 in the time of twi

Answer (score -1):

Compound time signature beats can be divided into just about any note grouping imaginable. The rhytms you can think of are as wide as the Lord's mercy and he is indeed very merciful. There is off course rhythms that enforce a compound sound and rhythms that may imply more of a 3/2 sound, but there is nothing really specific that leads you to dividing a dotted beat into three notes

Comment: But it's not a dotted note divided in 3. That's not what a triplet is.

Comment: No, a dotted note is divided into anything you want it to be. You can have an orange and divide it into 2 pieces, or three or five, or how many pieces you want it to be. You get note values up to 128th of a semi-breve, the options for dividing a dotted crotchet are really massive

Comment: A triplet is not the type of rhythm you would generally associate with compound time, but it still means the same 3 in the time of 2. You can have three quaver triplets and just have the third regular quaver and there your dotted crotchet is done

Comment: @Neil, yeah thats it... that is why I was confused. Triplets are not usually associated with compound time

Comment: This answer is still not clear, at least to me.

Comment: This does not anwer the original question at all. In fact, it's in essence simply stating the obvious

Answer (score -1):

Here is a table showing the types of regular time signatures:

| Meter Type | Beat Value | Time Signature |  | Meter Type | Beat Value | Time Signature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Simple duple | crotchet | 2/4 |  | Compound duple | dotted crotchet | 6/8 |
| Simple duple | minim | 2/2 |  | Compound duple | dotted minim | 6/4 |
| Simple triple | quaver | 3/8 |  | Compound triple | dotted quaver | 9/16 |
| Simple triple | crotchet | 3/4 |  | Compound triple | dotted crotchet | 9/8 |
| Simple triple | minim | 3/2 |  | Compound triple | dotted minim | 9/4 |
| Simple quadruple | quaver | 4/8 |  | Compound quadruple | dotted quaver | 12/16 |
| Simple quadruple | crotchet | 4/4 |  | Compound quadruple | dotted crotchet | 12/8 |
| Simple quadruple | minim | 4/2 |  | Compound quadruple | dotted minim | 12/4 |

Comment: I've formatted your table, but you should probably add some further explanation to the rest of substance in the question.